# Angular UI Grid date not formatting properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, filter, angular-ui-grid

I am using Angular's UI Grid to display a number of columns, but I cannot get the date column to format properly.

It is appearing as `/Date(1451346632162-0000)/`, etc.

I am trying to filter it in my gridOptions, but am having no luck:

```
// Removed Unrelated Column Defs

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'Date', field:'DateAdded', 
      /* First filter attempt */ cellTemplate: "<div>{{COL_FIELD | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</div>", 
      /* Second Filter Attempt */ cellFilter:"date:'dd-MM-yyyy'"
    }
```

I've tried variations of these that I found in the documentation with no luck - `cellFilter: "date"` and `cellFilter: "longDate"`

Any idea why these filter attempts are not working and the date is still appearing in this format?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to figure out what is stopping the regular filtering from working on the JSON date field, but here is the workaround I am using in the meantime (in case anyone has similar issues):

```
function formatDates(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var currentValue = data[i].DateAdded
            var dateString = currentValue.substr(6);
            var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
            var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = currentTime.getDate();
            var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
            var date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
            data[i].DateAdded = date;
        }
}
```

If anyone has any idea what is stopping the regular filtering from working please post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assure that you are actually using a Date object. If you're receiving the data from a database, it may not be a Date. When you query the database on the client side, you may need to do as follows: data.map(function(datum){ datum.DateAdded = new Date(datum.DateAdded) }).

This assures all dates are proper date objects.